# Python cant excecute SQL statement made from a optionsmenu

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

```
"""
Methode die das gesamte Menue realisiert
"""
def menueFrame():

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('800x600')
window.title('Auswahl der Schwerpunkte') 

db.connect()

schwerpunkte_neu = []
schwerpunkte_neu = db.getSchwerpunkte()


# Definiere die Variablen für die Schwerpunkte je DropDown Menue
variable1 = tk.StringVar(window, value='- select -')
variable2 = tk.StringVar(window, value='- select -')
variable3 = tk.StringVar(window, value='- select -')
variable4 = tk.StringVar(window, value='- select -')
variable5 = tk.StringVar(window, value='- select -')

# Label welches die Begrüßung enthält
greetings = tk.Label(window, text='Dies ist das Auswahlmenue fuer Ihr Praktikum. Wählen Sie nach die Schwerpunkte, die Sie von Ihrem Praktikum erwarten \n ')
greetings.pack()

# Hier werden die Schwerpunkte aus der Methode geholt
variable1.set(schwerpunkte_neu[0])
#print(schwerpunkte_neu)
variable2.set(schwerpunkte_neu[0])
variable3.set(schwerpunkte_neu[0])
variable4.set(schwerpunkte_neu[0])
variable5.set(schwerpunkte_neu[0])


# Auswahlmenue der ersten Eingenschaft
matrikel = tk.Label(window, text='Bitte Ihre Matrikelnummer einegeben: ')
e0_matrikel = tk.Entry(window)
matrikel.pack()
e0_matrikel.pack()


e1_label = tk.Label(window, text='Bitte wählen Sie einen Schwerpunkt aus:')
e1_label.pack()

dDe1 = tk.OptionMenu(window, variable1, *schwerpunkte_neu)
dDe1.pack()


# Auswahlmenue der zweiten Eingenschaft
e2_label = tk.Label(window, text='Bitte wählen Sie einen Schwerpunkt aus:')
e2_label.pack()


dDe2 = tk.OptionMenu(window, variable2, *schwerpunkte_neu)
dDe2.pack()

# Auswahlmenue der dritten Eingenschaft
e3_label = tk.Label(window, text='Bitte wählen Sie einen Schwerpunkt aus:')
e3_label.pack()


dDe3 = tk.OptionMenu(window, variable3, *schwerpunkte_neu)
dDe3.pack()

# Auswahlmenue der vierten Eingenschaft
e4_label = tk.Label(window, text='Bitte wählen Sie einen Schwerpunkt aus:')
e4_label.pack()

dDe4 = tk.OptionMenu(window, variable4, *schwerpunkte_neu)
dDe4.pack()


# Auswahlmenue der fuenften Eingenschaft
e5_label = tk.Label(window, text='Bitte wählen Sie einen Schwerpunkt aus:')
e5_label.pack()

dDe5 = tk.OptionMenu(window, variable5, *schwerpunkte_neu)
dDe5.pack()


# Button zum Senden des SQL-Query
submit = tk.Button(text='Submit', fg='green',command=lambda : db.sendInfo(e0_matrikel.get(),variable1.get(),variable2.get(),variable3.get(),variable4.get(),variable5.get()))
submit.pack()    
# Button um die mainloop zu verlassen - beendet nicht das gesamte programm
close = tk.Button(text='Weiter', fg='red', command= window.destroy)
close.pack()

window.mainloop()

#
# Schritt zwei des Algorithmus
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('800x600')
window.title('Auswahl der Schwerpunkte - Ihr Ergebnis')


# Label welches die Begrüßung enthält
greetings = tk.Label(window, text='Auf Grundlage Ihrer Angaben, ist eine folgende Deckung ermittelt worden: \n ')
greetings.pack()

compared = tk.StringVar()
ergebnis = tk.Button(text='Ergebnis anzeigen', fg = 'green', command = lambda : db.compare(variable1.get(),variable2.get(),variable3.get(),variable4.get(),variable5.get()))
ergebnis.pack()

#result = tk.Message(window, text= str(db.compare(variable1.get(),variable2.get(),variable3.get(),variable4.get(),variable5.get() )))
#result.pack()


ende = tk.Button(text='Beenden', fg='red', command=window.destroy)
ende.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

## Part two

```
    def getSchwerpunkte():
"""
Mit dieser Methode sollen alle SQL-Befehle die mit SELECT zusammenhaengen durchgefuehrt werden
"""
liste = []

with mycurser as cursor:
    sql1 = "SELECT * FROM schwerpunkte" 

    try:
        cursor.execute(sql1)

        result = cursor.fetchall()
        liste = [row[0] for row in result]

            #liste.append(row[0])


            #print(liste)
    except:
            print("Oops! Something wrong")
connection.commit()




return liste


    def sendInfo(matNr,pick1,pick2,pick3,pick4,pick5):    
with mycurser as cursor:
    sql = "INSERT INTO student(MatrikelNr,Schwerpunkt1,Schwerpunkt2,Schwerpunkt3,Schwerpunkt4,Schwerpunkt5) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)" 
    val = (matNr ,pick1 ,pick2 ,pick3 ,pick4,pick5)


    try:


        cursor.execute(sql,val)

            #result = cursor.fetchall()


    except:
            print("Oops! Something wrong (sendInfo)" ,)

connection.commit()
```

'''

So, while working with python we wanted to created an list from the database, thats the method getSchwerpunkte(). Before we used an dictionary, but wanted it to be more dynamic.
While this works, sendInfo now isnt working anymore, it did before.
the optionmenu from also shows an error:

'No value for argument 'value' in constructor call'

our GUI works, but if we want to submit, it will wont excecute the query.

Any Idea where we are lacking?

thanks in advance

Comment: Which of these functions takes `value` as an argument?

Comment: You've posted way too much code. If the problem is with translating an option menu to a sql query, we don't need much more code than the option menu and the code that builds a query from it, and enough code to tie it all together.

Comment: Which database you use?

Comment: Can't use `variable1` .. `variable5` after first `mainloop()` as their master is destroyed.

Comment: @BryanOakley well, i thought it was important for the problem, but ill try next time.

Comment: @acw1668 so how can I change it to work?

Comment: @acw1668 we are using mysql